# Two domain pointing to same IP address

Tags: ip, cross-domain, subdomain, pagerank, inbound

I have domain like `www.abc.in` and would like to buy `www.abc.com` . As everyone is used to .com . I'm little bit confuse if two domain point to same `IP address`  will it effect 
my

1) Alexa rank.
2) Page rank.
3) Inbound and outbound links

If your answer is yes , please suggest me how can i solve this issue .

Comment: Can't you make your alternate domain redirect to your actual domain? Would avoid all possible issues

Comment: Will it increase  access time ...?? or any hidden drawback ??

Comment: Only very slightly on the first request (this is negligible), after that it's redirected to your main domain and it works exactly as before. And a drawback we know about wouldn't really be hidden now would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect `www.abc.com` to `www.abc.in` so if someone opens `.com` domain it automatically opens `.in`. Otherwise if you want to use `.com` only then you can make `301 redirects` which is SEO friendly and your ranking will not be affected. Still, I would prefer 1st one personally

Comment: can you please explain me more about 301 redirect .

Comment: @chetan: You should specify what you already know (i.e. how much you googled and which pages you read already) so we don't have to re-explain things and waste time.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen what are the drawbacks of 301 redirect.

Comment: @chetan: Why do you assume there are any?

Comment: @chetanSaini 301 redirects are SEO friendly, I dont think there are any harms